# php proximity script - how to calculate the number of words/characters between 2 given terms/words?

Tags: php, proximity

Basically - I want to calculate the "Proximity" of various terms.
By "proximity" I means Specifically the number of spaces/characters/words that sit between them.

Example:

Terms = Word1 / Word2
Chunk = "*blah **Word1** blah blah blah blah blah **Word2** blah*"
Proximity = Word1-Word2:5
THe script would see the 2 terms, locate them and then see the distance based on the words that lay between them.

A more advanced version would be to examine the semantic structure - and identify whether the terms occur within the same semantic element, or a sibling, or a parent etc.
Thus proximity discovery of terms may be within the same paragraph, or in sequential paragraphs, or under the same "parent" (heading) but otherwise separate etc.

Further - introducing things like word stemming/relationships/soundings at a later date may be useful too.

.

I've looked around the net (Google, here, php forums, php script sites).
Not seeing anything like it.
I can see tools on some sites that do similar (limited) - usually SEO based tools.
I want to be able to apply this to "text" in general ... as I may apply it to uploaded word/txt files etc.

I'm not seeing any real examples - so I can only assume it's mroe than a trifle to code it.

The question is - how can I do this?
How would I handle variant order of the words (Word1+Word2 / Word2+Word1)?
How could I handle identifying proximity within/outside of the same element/structure?

Hoping someone can shed some light/make some suggestions.

Comment: -dotNetkow- Fair enough on the revision - but "word" is a little generic,
maybe teh flag/tag should be set as "MSWord" or similar?
That - or start assigning "detail" values to the tags, so people don't assign what is deemed as non-relevant terms

Comment: I agree - we have a "msword" tag which makes sense for Word.  I'll edit the "wiki" on both tags to clarify.

Comment: Thank you - it can be confusing for people, as there are so many possible words to use, and so many definitions/implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do a lot of this kind of search on a given text, you could begin by indexing the whole text into a database containing the word, its position in the text, and the paragraph number (if needed). Then, you could select all the Word1 and Word2 positions, and it shouldn't be too hard to infer the minimal distance.

**Edit:**
Here is a try for a simple algorithm for a one-shot, without using database.

1. Remove any html and punctuation to keep only the words
2. Search for the first occurrence of Word1
3. Count the number of words (or chars, or spaces) until you reach next occurrence of Word2
4. If you reach Word1 again before reaching Word2, restart the counter
5. Record the distance, then continue to repeat steps 2-5 to get other occurrences of Word1 and Word2

Comment: Not a bad idea, but only if you have to search **a lot**.

Comment: Otherwise, you can index only Word1 and Word2, and it can be in an array instead of a database.

Comment: okay.  Well, I was hoping mroe of a "one-shot" or "throw-away" type of deal.  Ading stuff to a DB only to discard it after the resutls seems a little excessive.  So reading into a variable/array would likely achieve much the same, but be temporary.  //  So we are looking at mapping the position of each word (assign a value based on position), then compare the positional value of the terms (Word1@28, Word2@37, the proximity = (37-28) 8.

Comment: So I'd have to break the content down into chunks for $var.  I suppose I could allocate multiple positional scores ... not just the word order, but the semantic/structure position as well?  // I'll need to not only break things up - but idetnify what chunks are what, and handle things as a "whole" (because I need to see what the positional difference is, even if it's difference paragraphs), and as parts (so I can score up sibling/child/parent relationships). // So - the question is - how?

Comment: So I'd have to what?  note the terms I'm looking for. Put the content in as an html-stripped block and then note the positional scores that pertain.  Then take the original and break it down into semantic chunks (possibly nested, or note how deep?).  Then I can use the previously noted position scores to do lookups, and rate them? // Any better ideas?  Have I missed anything?

Comment: -Charles Brunet-  Thank you ... that sounds a little more do-able for me, and logical too :D.  I'll have a go and see what I can get going.